# How to remove the 'V' symbol from statusbar

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notification-icons, themes, icon-packs

I have an Android 6.0 running device as it has VoLTE support it shows this not so compliance icon with my theme.

Is there any way to get rid of this icon means can I hide this ?

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: May be possible - if your device is rooted, please edit to add device details and root status

Comment: What details you want and if it was easy to root a marshmallow then dear why I would ask this question here

Comment: If it's not rooted this is near impossible.

Comment: Nothing is impossible when it comes to Android.

Comment: Nothing is impossible when you are rooted. If you do not have root, there are plenty of things that are just not possible to do.